# How to add MongoDB Atlas cloud database in KeystoneJS v5

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

I have database server on MongoDB Atlas Cloud. 
I can Setup Keystonejs 5 with MongoDB local database but I don't to what Keystonejs expect for database connection string and settings.

below detail may useful to understand my issue

## Mongoose Database Adapter

### Usage

```js
const { MongooseAdapter } = require('@keystonejs/adapter-mongoose');

const keystone = new Keystone({
  name: 'My Awesome Project',
  adapter: new MongooseAdapter(),
});
```

### API `new MongooseAdapter(options)`

#### `options.mongoUri` (optional)

This is used as the `uri` parameter for `mongoose.connect()`.

***Default:*** Environmental variable (see below) or `'mongodb://localhost/<DATABASE_NAME>'`

If not specified, KeystoneJS will first look for one of the following environmental variables:

- `CONNECT_TO`,
- `DATABASE_URL`,
- `MONGO_URI`,
- `MONGODB_URI`,
- `MONGO_URL`,
- `MONGODB_URL`,
- `MONGOLAB_URI`,
- `MONGOLAB_URL`

If none of these are found a connection string is derived with a `DATABASE_NAME` from the KeystoneJS project name.

#### Mongoose Options (optional)

Additional Mongoose config options are passed directly through to `mongoose.connect()`.

See the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect) for a detailed list of options.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an environment variable that matches one of the ones listed in the question and then set that environment variable to be the connection string that MongoDB atlas cloud gives you.

I added a .env file to my project and then added an entry for `MONGO_URI` there, then used the dotenv package.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding `.env` file or you can directly pass `mongoUri` to adapter.

See the code below:

```
const keystone = new Keystone({
  name: 'My Awesome Project',
  adapter: new MongooseAdapter({mongoUri:"mongodb+srv://....."}),
});
```